# Setting up password-less ssh for hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, ssh, hdfs

I'm trying to set up a local, password-less ssh to use with hadoop on ubuntu and it's fighting me every step of the way. Originally I was able to run start-dfs.sh but I realized that I was running it was root, and you're not supposed to do that (so I understand).

I've been using the instructions from here:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

but most sites seem to have the same three steps:

```
  $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  $ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
  $ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I'm not even getting an error...when I try to run `ssh localhost` I get a password prompt and nothing I enter appeases it. To be honest, I don't even mind entering a password for ssh, as long as the hdfs stuff works.

My sshd_config file has changed a lot from searching for solutions, so I've uploaded it below just in case there are problems. I'm not sure what else to provide but if anyone needs logs or outputs, I'll be happy to provide them. Thanks in advance.

http://www.vaughn-s.net/hadoop/sshd_config

Comment: Post the debug log, have a look into the server logs, turn on debug log level on server. It is not enough information in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have collected a log and posted it to: http://www.vaughn-s.net/hadoop/result.txt

Comment: The key is rejected. The server debug log will tell you more.

Comment: There's no server, though - this is all being done locally.

Comment: Then you are running the ssh server locally ...

Comment: Right, I understand that. But when I try to run one of the hadoop services I'm prompted for a password and nothing I enter is accepted.


`vaughn@vaughn-notebook:/$ cd /usr/local/hadoop
vaughn@vaughn-notebook:/usr/local/hadoop$ sbin/start-dfs.sh
17/07/10 17:12:49 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
vaughn@localhost's password: 
vaughn@localhost's password: localhost: Permission denied, please try again.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148831/discussion-between-lengthy-preamble-and-jakuje).

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below URL which has the step by step with visualization

https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

**Hope this Helps!!!...**

Example

Setup Environment

SSH Client : 192.168.0.12 ( Fedora 21 )

SSH Remote Host : 192.168.0.11 ( CentOS 7 )

Step 1: Create Authentication SSH-Kegen Keys on – (192.168.0.12)

```
   [tecmint@tecmint.com ~]$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
   Generating public/private rsa key pair.
   Enter file in which to save the key (/home/tecmint/.ssh/id_rsa): [Press enter key]
   Created directory '/home/tecmint/.ssh'.
   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Press enter key]
   Enter same passphrase again: [Press enter key]
   Your identification has been saved in /home/tecmint/.ssh/id_rsa.
   Your public key has been saved in /home/tecmint/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
   The key fingerprint is:
   5f:ad:40:00:8a:d1:9b:99:b3:b0:f8:08:99:c3:ed:d3 tecmint@tecmint.com
   The key's randomart image is:
   +--[ RSA 2048]----+
   |        ..oooE.++|
   |         o. o.o  |
   |          ..   . |
   |         o  . . o|
   |        S .  . + |
   |       . .    . o|
   |      . o o    ..|
   |       + +       |
   |        +.       |
   +-----------------+
```

Step 2: Create .ssh Directory on – 192.168.0.11

```
   [tecmint@tecmint ~]$ ssh sheena@192.168.0.11 mkdir -p .ssh
   The authenticity of host '192.168.0.11 (192.168.0.11)' can't be established.
   RSA key fingerprint is 45:0e:28:11:d6:81:62:16:04:3f:db:38:02:la:22:4e.
   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
   Warning: Permanently added '192.168.0.11' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
   sheena@192.168.0.11's password: [Enter Your Password Here]
```

Step 3: Upload Generated Public Keys to – 192.168.0.11

```
   [tecmint@tecmint ~]$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh sheena@192.168.0.11 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
   sheena@192.168.1.2's password: [Enter Your Password Here]
```

Step 4: Set Permissions on – 192.168.0.11

```
   [tecmint@tecmint ~]$ ssh sheena@192.168.0.11 "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
   sheena@192.168.0.11's password: [Enter Your Password Here]
```

Step 5: Login from 192.168.0.12 to 192.168.0.11 Server without Password

```
   [tecmint@tecmint ~]$ ssh sheena@192.168.0.11
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16673477)

Comment: @JohnMoutafis Made the necessary changes!!!...Thanks  for your suggestion,I will always keep your suggestion in mind while posting!!!...